# Extracting color of a image and then append again cause the edge problem

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing

i have an image and the want to extract the color of image and save it to a empty transperancy images with same size as the original one.
I used clustering method to get a number of cluster, then i jump pixel by pixel in the original image and calculat the euclid distance between pixel with each element of the cluster arrary. The pixel with closest distance with the cluster[idx] will go to a transparency image.

- After that, i stacking those extracted image and i get the same image as the original one, but when i zoom in, zoom out that image. the edge of image not smooth.

How can i solve this?
[the combined image after zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09vvO.jpg)
[the image combined no zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vC1KO.jpg)

I tried dilate and gaussian blur in the alpha channel but seem not work

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for this problem already,
There are an element in CSS called image-rendering that save me in this case"

```html
<head>
    <style>
   
        .image-container img {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: auto;
            height: auto;
            image-rendering: pixelated;
            image-rendering: optimizeQuality; /* For webkit browsers */
            image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges; /* For Firefox */
            image-rendering: -o-crisp-edges; /* For Opera */
            image-rendering: crisp-edges; /* For IE */
        }
    </style>
</head>
```

- But i know there are other solutions like expanding and then feather the edge of the transparent image